# How to Checkout file to Default ChangeList?

Tags: c#, perforce, p4api.net

Here is my code I want to check out file to default changelist.

But I don't know my default changlist ID. How can I get it?

[image]

```
string command = "-c";
string f = filePath;

cmd = new P4Command(p4, "add", true, command, changelist.Id.ToString(), "-f", f);
rslt = cmd.Run();

f = filePath.Replace("@", "%40");

cmd = new P4Command(p4, "edit", true, command, changelist.Id.ToString(), f);
rslt = cmd.Run();

cmd = new P4Command(p4, "reopen", true, command, changelist.Id.ToString(), f);
rslt = cmd.Run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to overcomplicate things -- it's called the "default" because it's literally the default when you don't specify a changelist.  The "default changelist" isn't really a changelist; it's just a collection of files open on your client that don't belong to a numbered changelist yet.

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 edit foo
//stream/main/foo#4 - opened for edit

C:\Perforce\test>p4 opened
//stream/main/foo#4 - edit default change (text)
```

I think in terms of your code this is:

```
cmd = new P4Command(p4, "edit", true, f);
rslt = cmd.Run();
```

Just leave off the "-c" (which stands for "changelist") and the changelist number.

If you need to move a file out of a numbered change and into the default change you can use the `reopen` command as described in `p4 help reopen`:

```
    reopen -- Change the filetype of an open file or move it to
              another changelist

    p4 reopen [-c changelist#] [-t filetype] file ...

        ...

        The target changelist must exist; you cannot create a changelist by
        reopening a file. To move a file to the default changelist, use
        'p4 reopen -c default'.
```

Comment: yes it's work for "edit" , but it's not working on "reopen" ~

Comment: For a file that's *already* open in a numbered change, where you want to move it out of that change, you'd use `reopen -c default`, as described in `p4 help reopen`.  Added that to the answer.  For every command that opens a file (`add`, `edit`, `delete`, `integrate`, `copy`, `reconcile`, etc) you only need to specify `-c change` if you want to open it in a specific (existing) numbered change.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found answer. dont input changeId , just input keyword : "default" like this.

```
string command = "-c";
cmd = new P4Command(p4, "add", true, command, "default", "-f", f);
cmd = new P4Command(p4, "edit", true, command, "default", f);
cmd = new P4Command(p4, "reopen", true, command, "default", f);
```